# IBM message broker V 6.1 esql

Tags: message, messagebroker

I have been using message broker 6.1 for integration to read a xml file into database. I am basically hard-coding the entities in esql to select from the path and inserting into database (oracle).

```
PROCEDURE Populate_SUMMARY_CG() 
    BEGIN 

        DECLARE B INTEGER 1; 
        DECLARE C INTEGER; 

        SET C = CARDINALITY(InputRoot.XMLNSC.Summary_CG[]); 

SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.IRR.SUMMARY[] =  ---> (will be changed to db insert Summary table in oracle)
SELECT
        coalesceChar(P.ID) as ID,
         CastTimestampUTCtoChar(P.CreationTime) as CREATIONTIME,
        CastTimestampUTCtoChar(P.UpdateTime) as UPDATETIME,
            -- to be removed
        FROM InputRoot.XMLNSC.Summary_CG[] AS P;
END;
```

We have to convert a hierarchical structure (XML) to relational. I have to keep repeating the code for each entity in XML mapping to a different target table using selects in XML...

Is there any way to use a recursive function (like in java) to have a generic function to read elements defined in a path and inserting them into table. I want to use a generic function to read and write (the values changed are the element names and column names on target side and table names.)

Comment: The code in your question makes no sense, it is not even syntactically correct. Procedures and functions can be called recursively in message broker.